# Sort List object values alphabetically

Tags: asp.net, list, sorting, ajaxcontroltoolkit, cascadingdropdown

I have this variable

```
Dim values As New List(Of AjaxControlToolKit.CascadingDropDownNameValue)
```

I'm adding new values like so:

```
While reader.Read
    values.Add(New CascadingDropDownNameValue(reader("title").ToString, reader("id").ToString))
End While
```

After that I want to sort the `values` list by alphabetical order based on the `title` field.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? I'm assuming Title property is the first argument that you are passing.

```
Dim sortedValues = values.OrderBy(Function(cascadingItem) cascadingItem.Title)
```